# Why does Chrome use the IE settings for connection?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Why does Chrome use the IE settings for connection ?

If i change proxy setting in one, it is automatically changed in another.

How can i  have different setting for each browser ?

Note: For firefox i'm able to set independent proxy setting

```
IE Version:     8.0.7061.17514
chrome Version: 29.0.1547.76 m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "Target" field of the "Google Chrome" Shortcut, add the following parameter:

```
--proxy-server=proxy server:port
```

Here is an example (for Chrome running on Windows 2008 and using a squid proxy):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server=192.168.nnn.nnn:3128
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome doesn't have its own Network Settings. It uses the settings provided by your Operating System, so they will always be the same as IE.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en