# Workaround to have a Standalone proxy settings for Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, proxy

I did a search in [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?num=100&es_sm=93&q=how%20to%20change%20proxy%20settings%20in%20Chrome%20without%20affecting%20IE&oq=how%20to%20change%20proxy%20settings%20in%20Chrome%20without%20affecting%20IE&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.5344.8766.0.8954.16.14.2.0.0.2.360.1128.10j1j0j2.13.0.ecpfrac...0...1c.1.36.serp..9.7.673.lUGVyk-OEPc) and also in this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118181/why-does-chrome-use-the-ie-settings-for-connection). But I could not see any useful information.

Now, I use both IE for Work VPN and Chrome for personal activities and need to use different proxy settings.

Google Chrome doesn't have its own Network Settings. It uses the [settings provided by your Operating System](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en), so they will always be the same as IE.

So the question is `Whether we can have any possible workaround to overcome this and have a standalone proxies for both the browsers, rather than a shared one?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome can use its own proxy setting but this function is hidden from UI.

To do this, you'll have to set up a shortcut in the desktop first (*or actually use one that you already have*), and then adjust target of the shortcut.

1. Go to the shortcut you use to open Google Chrome.
2. Right-click the shortcut and select Properties.
3. To use a different proxy server, go to the Target text box. Go to the end of the text, add a space and input the following: `--proxy-server="ipaddress:port"`

[image]

So if your proxy has IP `192.168.1.5` and uses port `8080` you should add something like this `--proxy-server="192.168.1.5:8080"` to the end. Make sure to include the quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me either. After using this trick, I check IE and it appears the proxy settings have changed in there too, based on settings I put in the chrome shortcut.

Comment: This doesn't work. Windows gives an error to the effect that the text in the Target Box is not valid. Trying to run from the command lines gives an error stating "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: This does work, however, if there was already a version of chrome running then the new shortcut won't make a difference: you have to exit all chrome instances and start a new process using this shortcut

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work per profile. Chrome shares the proxy settings of the first Chrome instance that is launched on the system among all Chrome instances, even when instances use different profiles.